# Jogl Push/Pop Matrix not working or I misunderstand

Tags: jogl

So I have the following calls in my display.  the display method has no calls to any state change methods other than loadIdentity.  The display method then calls the following.

```
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotated(m_angle, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    m_angle += 5;
    cubeBySquare(gl,0.2);
    gl.glTranslated( 0.5,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    cubeByVertex(gl,0.2);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

The two methods are shown below - basically one attempts to draw a cube using rotate and translate (cubeBySquare) and the other succeeds in drawing a cube by specifying all of the vertices explicitly (cubeByVertex).

```
protected   void                cubeBySquare(GL2 gl,double side)
{
    /*
     *  front - blue
     *  
     *  draw the square and leave it where it is on XY plane
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    /*
     *  back - green
     *  
     *  draw square and push it backwards on the Z axis
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    gl.glTranslated( 0.0 ,  0.0 , -side);
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    /*
     *  lhs - cyan
     *  
     *  draw square and rotate -90 around Y axis
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(0.0,1.0,1.0);
    gl.glRotated(-90, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    /*
     *  rhs - red
     *  
     *  draw square, rotate -90 aeound Y axis, translate to rhs on X axis
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    gl.glRotated(-90, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gl.glTranslated( side,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    /*
     *  top - mauve
     *  
     *  draw square, rotate -90 around X axis, translate along Y axis
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(1.0,0.0,1.0);
    gl.glRotated( 90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.glTranslated( 0.0 ,  side ,  0.0 );
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    /*
     *  bottom - yellow
     *  
     *  draw square, rotate -90 around X-axis
     */
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glColor3d(1.0,1.0,0.0);
    gl.glRotated(-90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    square(gl,side);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}

protected   void                cubeByVertex(GL2 gl,double side)
{
    gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS); // of the color cube

    // Front - blue
    gl.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side,  0.0 );

    // Back - green
    gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 , -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 , -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side, -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side, -side);

    // Left - cyan
    gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 , -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side, -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side,  0.0 );

    // Right - red
    gl.glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 , -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side, -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side,  0.0 );

    // Top - mauve 
    gl.glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  side, -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  side, -side);

    // Bottom - yellow
    gl.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 ,  0.0 );
    gl.glVertex3d( side,  0.0 , -side);
    gl.glVertex3d( 0.0 ,  0.0 , -side);

    gl.glEnd(); // of the color cube
}
```

The result is unexpected as you can see in the image.  I have tried to see where my logic is wrong but I cannot find any thing unexpected.  It looks to me like the push/pop matrix is not really clearing the matrix from the stack.  Which probably means I am not using it correctly - yet it looks like most of the examples for hierarchical drawing that I have found on the web.

It seem there is no way to include an image here which make the explanation clumsy.

Basically thr cubeBySquare version rotates and translates all over the shop and not where I expect - thinking previous rotate and translates are affecting the more recent endering even though I have each square bracketed by push/pop matrix

Comment: You can include all kinds of images, just click the image button on the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

After racking my brains for the last 3 days.  Suddenly the light dawned - the order of applying rotation then translation was messing with my head.  I forgot the rotation meant that the coordinate system had rotated so after this point the use of absolute coordinates when the frame of reference had rotated meant all sorts of unexpected results - give my incorrect assumption.

Slightly embarrassed but happy to finally understand.